# React native mobx is not working in class Component

Tags: react-native, mobx

// Here is my mobx store

```
import { makeObservable, observable, action } from 'mobx';
import {fakeLoginApi} from './Common'

class LoginStore {
  username = '';
  password = '';
  isValidEmail=false;
  isValidPassword=false;

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      username: observable,
      password: observable,
      isValidEmail:observable,
      isValidPassword:observable,
      setUsername: action,
      setPassword: action,
      setValidEmail:action,
      setValidPassword:action,
      login: action,
    });
  }

  setUsername(username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  setPassword(password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  setValidEmail(isValidEmail){
    this.isValidEmail=isValidEmail
  }

  setValidPassword(isValidPassword){
    this.isValidPassword=isValidPassword
  }
  async login(token) {
    console.log('username:', this.username);
    console.log('password:', this.password);
    // console.log('Logging in with token:', token);
  }
}

const loginStore = new LoginStore();
export default loginStore;
```

//Here is my login page which is a class component

```
class ClassComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleUsernameChange = this.handleUsernameChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
  }
  handleUsernameChange = text => {
    try {
      const validEmail = emailValidation(text);
      // console.log('validEmail',validEmail);
      if (validEmail) {
        loginStore.setUsername(text);
        loginStore?.setValidEmail(false);
      } else {
        loginStore.setUsername(text);
        loginStore?.setValidEmail(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('handleUserNameError', error);
    }
  };

  handlePasswordChange = text => {
    try {
      if (text.length < 8) {
        loginStore.setPassword(text);
        loginStore.setValidPassword(true);
      } else {
        loginStore.setPassword(text);
        loginStore.setValidPassword(false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('handlePasswordChangeError',error);
    }
  };

  handleLogin = () => {
    try {
      const validEmail = emailValidation(loginStore.username);

      if(!validEmail){
        loginStore?.setValidEmail(true)
      }else if(loginStore?.password.length < 8){
        loginStore?.setValidPassword(true)
      }else{
        alert(loginStore.username)
        // const token = 'your-token-here';
        // loginStore.login(token);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('handleLoginError',error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={LoginStyles?.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={LoginStyles?.textInput}
          placeholder="Username"
          // value={loginStore?.username}
          onChangeText={this.handleUsernameChange}
          keyboardType="email-address"
          autoCapitalize="none"/>
        {loginStore.isValidEmail ? (
          <Text style={LoginStyles?.errorMsg}>Enter email</Text>
        ) : null}

        <TextInput
          style={LoginStyles?.textInput}
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={this.handlePasswordChange}
          // value={loginStore?.password}
          secureTextEntry
        />
        {loginStore.isValidPassword ? (
          <Text style={LoginStyles?.errorMsg}>Enter Password</Text>
        ) : null}
        <Button title="Login" onPress={this.handleLogin} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default observer(ClassComponent);
```

//Here is my functional component

```
const FunctionalComponent = observer(() => {
  const handleUsernameChange = text => {
    try {
      const validEmail = emailValidation(text);
      console.log('validEmail', validEmail);
      if (validEmail) {
        loginStore.setUsername(text);
        loginStore?.setValidEmail(false);
      } else {
        loginStore.setUsername(text);
        loginStore?.setValidEmail(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('handleUserNameError', error);
    }
  };

  const handlePasswordChange = text => {
    try {
      if (text.length < 8) {
        loginStore.setPassword(text);
        loginStore.setValidPassword(true);
      } else {
        loginStore.setPassword(text);
        loginStore.setValidPassword(false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('handlePasswordChangeError', error);
    }
  };

  const handleLogin = () => {
    try {
      const validEmail = emailValidation(loginStore.username);
      if (!validEmail) {
        loginStore?.setValidEmail(true);
      } else if (loginStore?.password.length < 8) {
        loginStore?.setValidPassword(true);
      } else {
        // const token = 'your-token-here';
        // loginStore.login(token);
        alert(loginStore.username)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('handleLoginError', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={LoginStyles?.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={LoginStyles?.textInput}
        placeholder="Username"
        value={loginStore.username}
        onChangeText={handleUsernameChange}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        keyboardType="email-address"
      />
      {loginStore.isValidEmail ? (
        <Text style={LoginStyles?.errorMsg}>Enter email</Text>
      ) : null}
      <TextInput
        style={LoginStyles?.textInput}
        placeholder="Password"
        value={loginStore.password}
        onChangeText={handlePasswordChange}
        secureTextEntry
      />
      {loginStore.isValidPassword ? (
        <Text style={LoginStyles?.errorMsg}>Enter Password</Text>
      ) : null}
      <Button title="Login" onPress={handleLogin} />
    </View>
  );
});

export default FunctionalComponent;
```

I am developing a loginscreen with mobx for state management.The issue is class component is not working with mobx state update.Let's say for example if i type invalid email id it should Enter valid email text.Once the email is entered correctly the error text should disappear same way for password also if i enter password less than 8 characters it should show Enter valid password text once 8 characters entered in textinput the error text should disappear.

Note:-
The same validation is working perfectly in functional components as i expected.
But in class component its not working